# Android, How to pass the name of int variable to a popupwindow?

Tags: java, android, popupwindow

How can I pass the name of an int variable to a popupwindow when an image is clicked? I have set an int per image and I have a lot of images that I had set.

This is how I'm using the int in a textView on a PopupWindow.

```
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
// v.setTag(v);

case R.id.hsv1iv1:
ImageView ivpopup = (ImageView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.pv1);
intcount1++;         // I would like to pass this int name to the popup window. 
break;
case R.id.hsv2iv1:
ImageView ivpopup = (ImageView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.pv1);
intcount2++;         // I would like to pass this int name to the popup window. 
break;

LayoutInflater layoutInflater 
= (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null); 
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
popupView, 
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
popupWindow.update(0, 0, 800, 500);
ColorDrawable dw = new ColorDrawable(-005500);
popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(dw);
tvpwlikectr = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.liketv);


Button pwlikebtn =  (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.pwlikebtn);

Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);

pwlikebtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {

intcount1++;
tvpwlikectr.setText(Integer.toString(intcount1));  // this code doesn't work with the intcount1

}});
btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(View v) {

popupWindow.dismiss();

popupWindow.setTouchable(true);
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

}
 }
```

Comment: You really think that we can understand your issue with one line of code and such meaningless explanation? What is a popup window? Is that an AlertDialog? What are you talking about?

Comment: Is that similar to your question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020457/android-how-to-pass-the-name-of-int-variable-to-a-popupwindow

Comment: @Waza_Be I will try to elaborate more if needed. Your link refers to the same question. ??

Comment: it's impossible to understand what you want to achieve... Maybe more code would help

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain how you are setting the INT per image? Copying and pasting the code on how you set an INT per image would be helpful, because it's unclear what you mean by you are setting an INT per image.

Also, are you interested in the value of the int variable or the name of the variable? Showing how you are settings lots of images with int per image would help clarify what you are trying to do.

**-- adding answer after seeing the updated post with code --**

I would create an object that has the name you are interested in (i.e. intcount1) and an int to keep the actual value. After that, you can associate each button/ImaveView with that object with the view.setTag method, and get the value via view.getTag method. Here's an example:

```
private class MyTag {
    String mTagName;
    int mCount;
    MyTag(String tagName) {
       mTagName = tagName;
       mCount = 0;
    }
}

// in your onCreate or initializaion code somewhere
ImageView view1 = (ImageView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.hsv1iv1);
MyTag imageTag = new MyTag("intcount1");
view1.setTag(imageTag);
ImageView view2 = (ImageView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.hsv1iv1);

// this will go wherever you handle the onLongClick
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
   Object tag = v.getTag();
   if (tag instanceof MyTag) {
      MyTag myTag = (MyTag) tag;
      myTag.mCount++;
   }
}

// I'm assuming you are setting the text from the actual clicked object
// so this will go wherever you are setting the text/handling the click
public void onClick(View v) {
    Object tag = v.getTag();
    if (tag instanceof MyTag) {
       MyTag myTag = (MyTag) tag;
       myTag.mCount++;
       tvpwlikectr.setText(myTag.mTagName);
    }
}
```

The bottom line is, creating an object with name/count value, associate each View with its own object using the view.setTag() function, and when you need to read the values, use the view.getTag() to get the object and read the mTagName (the "variable" name) and the mCount (the "variable" value).

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: The images are from drawable that i set to horizontalView/imageViews. The INT that i'm trying pass to popupview is link to the image that was click. I passing the name of the iNT variable so that I can increment it when I press a button with in the Popup window. Basically, I'm implementing a LKE button for the image that i click.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I would have but I couldn't find the "add comment" link on the OP's post. I don't think I have the privilege to comment on other people's posts yet.

Comment: @MarvinD please update your questions with the code you are trying to explain, it would be much easier to understand and would help other people give you constructive feedback.

Comment: @tigerpenguin thx. I will try your suggestion. It looks doable but it looks like a lot of code for accessing a int name from a popup window.  What do you think about adding the onclick inside the case statement? I think adding the onclick inside the case creates repeat code.  `switch  - case image1: - pwlikebtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View v) { intcount1++; tvpwlikectr.setText(Integer.toString(intcount1));

Comment: @MarvinD Integer.toString(intCount1)) will give you the value of the intCount1, not the name of the variable. I thought you wanted to access the name of the int variable, not the value of it? The code is reusable because you can have all your buttons point to the same function, because each button/view will have its own tag associated with it. the setText(myTag.mTagName) will produce different results for each view, even though it's the same function

Comment: @tigerpenguin i'm only using Integer.toString(intCount1)) to show the current value of the int within the  popup then use the name to increment the int with real time update with a click of a button. Reusable code is good. Looks like your sugestion will work. I will try it and let you know. thx

Comment: @tigerpenguin I can't get this to work. I'm invoking this in the popup window which is diffrent view. So I don't think i can capture the settag from popup.   public void onClick(View v) {
    Object tag = v.getTag();
    if (tag instanceof MyTag) {
       MyTag myTag = (MyTag) tag;
       myTag.mCount++;
       tvpwlikectr.setText(myTag.mTagName);
    }
}